# Помогите понять как создать экземпляр класса

Tags: c#, winforms, классы, generics

Был у меня класс BaseClass выглядел как-то так:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form, IView
{
    protected IPresenter _presenter;

    public BaseForm(IPresenter presenter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presenter = new Presenter(this);
    }

    private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter.Retrive();
    }
}
```

Начал эксперементировать с универсальными типами в попытке создать универсальную форму для работы с базой данных.

Вот, что получилось

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GenericDemo
{
    public partial class BaseForm<T> : Form, IView where T : IPresenter
    {
        protected T _presenter;

        public BaseForm(T presenter)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _presenter = presenter;
        }

        private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _presenter.Retrive();
        }
    }

    public class Presenter : IPresenter
    {
        private readonly IView _view;

        public Presenter(IView view)
        {
            _view = view;
        }
        public void Retrive()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

Но уперся в проблему создания экземпляра.

При создании экземпляра класса `var form = new BaseForm<IPresenter>(new Presenter());` получаю ошибку

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'view' of 'Presenter.Presenter(IView)'

А как теперь создавать экземпляры получившегося универсального класса?

Comment: конструктор Presenter требует IView. должно быть что-то вроде `var frm = new BaseForm<IPresenter>(new Presenter(new View()));`

Comment: @Stack new View() не может быть. Конструктор Presenter должен получить ссылку на тот объект, который я создаю. Раньше вместо `_presenter = presenter;` было `_presenter = new Presenter(this);` Теперь нужен какой-то аналог.

Comment: Вас не смущает, что они оба зависят друг от друга одновременно? Таки обычно практикуют однонаправленную зависимость.

Comment: @Monk Что Вы имеете ввиду? Кто зависит друг от друга?

Comment: Форма от презентера и презентер от формы. По крайней мере, об этом говорят конструкторы.

Comment: @Monk Простите, я новичек этом деле и видимо что-то не понимаю. Но в чем именно Вы усматриваете зависимость формы (BaseForm) от представления (Presenter). Да и представление тоже, на мой взгляд, не зависит ни от какой конкретной формы. Не могли бы Вы более точно указать мне на то, в чем именно выражается зависимость BaseForm и Presenter?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin форма у вас хранит ссылку на свой презентер, презентер - хранит ссылку на свою форму. Проблем в принципе нет, но фактически, вы объединили уже два класса в один.

Comment: @Monk Форма содержит поле для хранения ссылки на презентер. Чтобы иметь возможность обращаться к методам презентера. Презентер, в свою очередь, содержит поле для хранения ссылки на представление, чтобы управлять им. А как же иначе? Я патюсь реализовать паттерн MVP (Passive View). В нем реализуются следующие связи V<->P->M. Чем моя реализация принципиально отличается от описанной [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter)?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin тем, что ваша вьюшка наружу выставляет запрос презентера. Тот код, что на вики, довольно очевиден - создавайте вьюшки, они сами создадут себе по презентеру. Ваш же код становится неочевиден - что создавать первым - презентер или вьюшку, особенно если учитывать, что каждый из них в свою очередь зависит от другого, т.е. правильного ответа нет ни в один момент времени. Это не критично, пока ваш код запускается и работает, но как только вам захочется натянуть на презентер другую вьюшку - скорее всего получится почти полная копия существующей вьюшки.

Comment: @Monk Спасибо Вам за терпеливое разъяснение. Теперь я кажется начал понимать о чём Вы говорите. Да, действительно, тот вариант который привел я - неправильный. И подозревая это я и задал вопрос, в надежде, что мене покажут как правильно. Собственно в ответе и представлен правильный вариант. Теперь вместо `_presenter = presenter;` используется `_presenter = presenterCreator(this);`. Тогда все становится очевидным, так?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin более-менее, хотя конструкция `new BaseForm<Presenter>(_form => new Presenter(_form));` выглядит тоже не сильно очевидно. Я бы скорее ожидал `new BaseForm<Presenter>();` который сам найдет как создать презентер.

Comment: @Monk да, согласен. Сама по себе конструкция `new BaseForm<Presenter>(_form => new Presenter(_form));` совсем не очевидна. Она хоть и решает поставленную задачу, но наверное другому программисту будет совершенно непонятно как создать экземпляр представления и ему придется попотеть. Но как же мне быть? Может Вы предложите свой вариант решения задачи дав ответ на мой вопрос? Только как вы вероятно заметили мне нужен развернутый ответ с рабочим примером.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin пользуйтесь тем, что работает. Красивых и удобных одновременно вариантов я тут не вижу. Можно сделать рефлекшном, с шансом упасть когда нибудь в будущем, либо сделать более неочевидное внутреннее устройство, ради удобного конструктора. Обе идеи ещё хуже того, что отмечено ответом. Поэтому - проще пока не трогать то, что работает. Автоматическая связка V-P по моему ни в одном проекте не была удобно реализована, в любом случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //...
    public BaseForm(Func<BaseForm<T>, T> presenterCreator)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presenter = presenterCreator(this);
    }
    //...
```

Использование:

```
var form = new BaseForm<Presenter>(_form => new Presenter(_form));
```