# Зачем нужен встроенный делегат Func?

Tags: c#

При решении [очередной проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479542/194602) опять сталкнулся со встроенным делегатом `Func`. Никак не могу понять его предназначение, как он работает и как устроен. Может кто-то на каком-то простом примере объяснить что это, для чего используется, как это работает и как этим пользоваться?

Comment: Func - это обычный делегат. также как и все делегаты является наследником специального класса MulticastDelegate. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479412/c-%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D1%8B/479414#479414)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Допустим мы имеем метод, который рисует графики различных функций, для простоты - алгебраических, вида y=f(x). Нашему методу все равно какую именно функцию данного вида рисовать, главное чтобы вид функции совпадал с заданным. тогда мы можем определить наш метод следующим образом:

```
 public void DrawFunc(Func<double,double> f)
 {
     for(double x = 0.0; x<1.0; x+=0.001)
     {
         double y = f(x);
         //и далее рисуем точки графика
     }
 }
```

Теперь для отрисовки графика нам нужно вызвать наш метод и передать ему подходящую функцию. Для Func< double, double> нам подойдет любая функция вида double FuncName(double ParamName), например Math.Sin. Вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
DrawFunc(Math.Sin);
```

Данный делегат, как и аналогичный ему Action используется в основном для быстрого объявления делегатов стандартного вида. Определено несколько отдельных делегатов вида Func< T1,...,T16,TResult>, и Action< T1,...,T16> которые могут принимать до 16-ти параметров (.NET 4+, до 4-х для .NET 3.5), типы которых указываются при объявлении. Кроме этого для Func необходимо указать тип возвращаемого значения TResult, у Action возвращаемое значение всегда void. Больше ничем от обычных делегатов они не отличаются.

[тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204937/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-func-%D0%B8-delegate?rq=1) уже обсуждалась очень похожая тема и есть еще немного информации

Comment: _"Func, и Action могут принимать до 16-ти параметров"_ -- точнее определены отдельные делегаты с разным количеством параметров.

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 7):

В дополнение к правильному ответу @rdorn:

`Func<>` — это по существу (с мелкими отличиями) тип, описывающий функцию. Вы можете передавать в другой метод или класс не только *данные*, но и *код*. Для этого вам нужно описать его тип, чтобы его можно было присваивать параметру, записывать в переменные или возвращать из функций. Вот `Func<>` именно для этого и служит.

Пример:

```
// применяет функцию дважды к начальному значению и выводит результат
void ApplyTwiceAndPrint(Func<int, int> f, int value)
{
    int result1 = f(value);
    int result2 = f(result1);
    Console.WriteLine(result2);
}

ApplyTwiceAndPrint(n => n * n, 3); // выводит 81
```

---

Как именно это работает внутри? Внутри `Func<...>` является **объектом** типа `MulticastDelegate`, у которого определена функция `Invoke(...)`. Когда вы пишете `f(value)`, компилятор поставляет вместо этого `f.Invoke(value)`, то есть, вызывает *метод* `Invoke`. (Да, тут есть немного компиляторного «сахара», которого нету, скажем, у Java.)

Внутри объект типа `MulticastDelegate` хитрым системно-зависимым образом содержит по сути указатель на метод, который и будет вызван в реализации метода `Invoke`.