# для этого ли нужны делегаты?

Tags: c#, делегаты

всем привет, только начал изучать делегаты. Имеется вот такой пример:

```
// Класс, метод которого будет сообщен с делегатом.
class MyClass
{
    // Создаем метод, который планируем сообщить с делегатом.
    public string Method(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}

// На 21-й строке создаем класс-делегата с именем MyDelegate,
// метод, который будет сообщен с экземпляром данного класса-делегата, 
// будет принимать один строковой аргумент и возвращать строковое значение.

public delegate string MyDelegate(string name);  // Создаем класс делегата. (1) 

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass();

        MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(instance.Method); // Создаем экземпляр делегата и сообщаем с ним метод. (2)


       string greeting = myDelegate.Invoke("djon"); // Вызываем метод сообщенный с делегатом. (3)


        Console.WriteLine(greeting);

        greeting = myDelegate("Grady Booch"); // Другой способ вызова метода сообщенного с делегатом. (3')

       Console.WriteLine(greeting);

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

ради интереса заменил строку:

```
string greeting = myDelegate("djon"); // Вызываем метод сообщенный с делегатом. (3)
```

на

```
string greetingg = MyClass.Method("djon");
```

и получил следующую ошибку от Visual Studio 2012 :

Ошибка 1
*Для  нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Delegates.MyClass.Method(string)" требуется ссылка на объект*

Ведь делегат это и есть объект, содержащий в себе указатели на методы.

Т.е этот пример с ошибкой допущенной мной ради эксперимента, и есть *наглядный* или можно сказать **жизненный** пример почему необходимо использовать делегаты?

Если так, то хорошо, если нет то приведите свои жизненные примеры использования делегатов.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479548/198316 мне кажется что тут есть достаточно подробный ответ на вопрос "зачем нужны делегаты"

Comment: @BadCats но ведь можно логически поразмышлять...... вы без делегата, просто можете написать `MyClass.Method("djon");` если метод `Method` не статический? Нет! Вам предварительно надо создать экземпляр  от класса, с которым он связан. Так почему здесь вы хотите чтоб рушились эти законы?

Answer (score 1):

Нет не правильно. Смотрите, здесь:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(instance.Method);
```

вы сначала создаете экземпляр класса, а уже потом на его основе делегат. А здесь:

```
string greetingg = MyClass.Method("djon");
```

вы пытаетесь работать с функцией как со статической, когда она таковой не является. Соответсвенно появляется ошибка.

К делегатам все это отношения не имеет, только к объектам и их членам.